# Netbeans - Glassfish server deployment error due to composite primary key

Tags: java, jpa, deployment, glassfish, netbeans-7

I'm currently having an issue with a BUILD FAILED error when deploying my Netbeans project to Glassfish server. I get the following error from the log:

Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field instrument] from the entity class [class entity.InstrumentExtRef] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.. Please see server.log for more details.

The table that's having the issue is instrument_ext_ref and has a composite primary key of the following fields: instrument_id and instrument_code_type.

The entity class that seems to have the problem - InstrumentExtRef - has the following declarations and annotations.

```
@EmbeddedId
protected InstrumentExtRefPK instrumentExtRefPK;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 16)
@Column(name = "reference")
private String reference;
@JoinColumn(name = "instrument_code_type", referencedColumnName = "code_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private InstrumentCodeType instrumentCodeType1;
@JoinColumn(name = "instrument_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Instrument instrument;
```

And the entity class containing the @EmbeddedId details (InstrumentExtRefPK) looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class InstrumentExtRefPK implements Serializable {
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "instrument_id")
private int instrumentId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 10)
@Column(name = "instrument_code_type")
private String instrumentCodeType;
```

Class InstrumentCodeType refers to table instrument_code_type which has a primary key code_type (the referenced column). Class Instrument refers to table instrument which itself has a composite primary key consisting of columns "id" (the referenced column) and column "exchange_exchange_code".

It seems obvious from the error message that the composite primary key in the InstrumentExtRef entity is the issue but based on my research of other similar (but not quite the same) issues I think my entity classes look OK. But I'm relatively new to this and may be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research on creating/uses of composite keys in entity classes I saw a subtle point in the error message I was receiving.

"...must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumn**s**". I wasn't using the @JoinColumns annotation. Or at least Netbeans didn't create the entity class that way. Probably because each join column is from a different source entity/table.

After correcting my entity classes as follows the project was able to be deployed successfully.

```
    @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "instrument_code_type", referencedColumnName = "code_type",    insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "instrument_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
private InstrumentCodeType instrumentCodeType1;
private Instrument instrument;
```

It was here that I started to see what the problem might be:
https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/ch02s02s06.html

I suspect that my next problem will be something to do with the fact that the composite primary key is made up of columns from two different entities - instrument and instrumentCodeType. But for now the above change got me past the build problem and if that next problem arises I'll deal with it separately.